# Mathematica 9 Citation

Tags: citation-management

I want to cite *Mathematica* 9.0.1 in my paper, but the standard citation is not available here http://support.wolfram.com/kb/472. Can you let me know where I can find it or give me one good sample (I don't know which tag should this question belong to, hence I just put it in `citation-management`).

Comment: Are you sure you want to cite 9.0? You don't use 9.0.1? There are quite a few differences between the two.

Comment: Sorry, i use 9.0.1. Just updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on http://support.wolfram.com/kb/472 and http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html I would use

```
Wolfram Research, Inc., Mathematica, Version 9.0, Champaign, IL (2012).
```